# subclassing of Model class and model functional API give different results in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

According to [the documentation for a model](https://keras.io/api/models/model/), there are two equivalent ways to create a model: by subclassing the Model class or using the functional API.

When I run the following code below, I get an error. Please tell me why this is so. Shouldn't the two models be identical?

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  def call(self, inputs):
    #x= tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))(inputs)
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    return self.dense2(x)

model = MyModel()

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model_fun = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model_fun.summary()
model.build((1,3,))
model.summary()

x= model_fun(tf.constant([[1,2,3]]))
y= model.call(tf.constant([[1,2,3]]))

assert((x.numpy()==y.numpy()).all())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neural network weights are initialized randomly, so there are no two identical models that will make the same exact prediction. That is, unless they are initialized with the same weights. If you set the random seed for weights initialization, the results will be the same:

```
self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                  kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))
```

Full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax,
                kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    return self.dense2(x)

model = MyModel()

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax,
                kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))(x)
model_fun = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model_fun.summary()
model.build((1,3,))
model.summary()

x= model_fun(tf.constant([[1,2,3]]))
y= model.call(tf.constant([[1,2,3]]))

assert((x.numpy()==y.numpy()).all())
```

```
[[0.74651927 0.00897978 0.04163173 0.00992385 0.1929454 ]]
[[0.74651927 0.00897978 0.04163173 0.00992385 0.1929454 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
  def call(self, inputs):
    # x= tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))(inputs)
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    return self.dense2(x)
```

Comment: my bad, that was an artifact from some fiddling I was doing. I copied the code verbatim from the keras tutorial as you said but still get the error.